# Python - Analyze Pcap FIle and extract interrupted connections

Tags: python, pcap

I am trying to do these steps :

1. read pcap file
2. analyze the packets and show connections that have not been set up properly

is it possible to extract information like this ?

i have write Python classes to extract Packet Header , Packet's Ethernet , Packet IP , Packet TCP information. i need guidance that is it possible to extract information like this ?  [hva_pcao.py](https://pastebin.com/RL8w6sTk) , [hva_pckt](https://pastebin.com/TBVWLzdF)

```
    rdr = pcap.open_offline('xsupport.pcap')
i = 0
for hdr, data in rdr:
    if i ==2:

        print(hdr)
        eth = Eth.decode(data)
        if eth is None: continue
        print(str(eth))
        ip = Ip.decode(eth.pl)
        if ip is None: continue
        print(str(ip))
        tcp = Tcp.decode(ip.pl)
        if tcp is None: continue
        print(str(tcp))
        print((repr(tcp.flags) + " - " + repr(tcp.kFlags_FIN) + " * " + repr(tcp.kFlags_ACK)))
        # break
```

My expected output is : analyze the packets and show connections that have not been set up properly

Comment: I consider the question as too broad. So far you are only showing some details about a packet and do not even tackle your main problem at all. In order to detect connections which are not setup properly you need to understand first what "connection" is and what "setup properly" means, i.e. dig into the details of TCP handshake, TCP flags and TCP sequence numbers. Only if you understand these details (which are not a programming problem) you can move forward with your task.